# VBA start at specific worksheet to link worksheets to list

Tags: vba, excel

I found this macro and wanted to tweak it so that it would start at a specific worksheet instead of running through the entire workbook.

```
Sub CreateLinksToAllSheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ActiveSheet.Name > sh.Name Then
        ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
            "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Next sh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  dim sh as Worksheet
  dim cell as Range
  dim cnt as Integer,idx as integer
  cnt=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
  idx=2 'any specific worksheet you want to start from

  for idx=2 to cnt
     set sh=ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets(idx)
    'rest of code goes here
   next
```

Comment: you are welcome. its great community to help each other